# How can I reach DataKey cells of GridView on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I need to reach DataKey columns of a GridView on the client side by a JavaScript function.

As they they are at least visually disabled on the UI I wonder if I can still reach them on client?

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "disabled on the UI"?

Comment: Well you do not see the DataKey colums, do you?

Comment: that depends on if you made the column visible or not. If the column is invisible(on serverside), it's not available on client-side at all(the html be not be rendered). But you could use a Hiddenfiel or whatelse you've made hidden with CSS(display:none) to get the ID on client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataKeys are not published to the client.  You have to write out the values some way, either use a hidden field in a template column (but don't set the column to visible="false") or some other means to get this to work.

I'm sure there are other ways too...

HTH.

Comment: I think I have to use css for this; display: none; so that it is rendered.